# Is it ok to use goto in catch?

Tags: c#, exception-handling

```
start:
try
{
    oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + ex.Message, "Error",
        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    if (res == DialogResult.Retry)
    {
        goto start;
    }
}
```

1. Is it ok to use `goto` operators, which lead outside a `try`/`catch` block?  What consequences may it lead to?
2. How can I make this code better?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm personally not a fan of goto's and to be honest I don't even know if I've ever used on in c#.  I tend to find they are a bit hard to follow as you have to jump around a bit too much and the natural flow of the code is potentially broken.

Here's an idea for using a different approach (Updated as suggested by [svick](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2041/svick))

```
string errorMessage;
while(!TryTableFill(myDataTable, out errorMessage))
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + errorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    if(result != DialogResult.Retry)
        break;
}

private boolean TryTableFill(myDataTable, out string errorMessage)
{
    errorMessage = string.Empty;

    try
    {
       oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable);
       return true;   
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {  
       errorMessage = ex.Message;
       return false;
    }       
}
```

or alternatively (I like this way but I'm not sure if it's better.  Added just to provide an alternative):

```
private boolean TryTableFill(myDataTable, out string errorMessage)
{
    errorMessage = string.Empty;

    try
    {
       oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {  
       errorMessage = string.Format("Error occured: {0}", ex.Message);
    }       

    return !string.isNullOrEmpty(errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to rely on the fact that a `Message` of an exception won't be `null` or empty? I think using multiple `return` statements (one in `try`, one in `catch`) would be a better solution here.

Comment: @svick valid point.  I've updated answer to reflect this.  cheers.

Comment: How about limiting the number of attempts? Also, sometimes you should capitalize the s in `String`. Run StyleCop on your code and you will see.

Comment: @Leonid  Fair point.  I think it's more of a style (team) preference though so might leave that to the OP to decide.  Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or.  I tend to listen to his suggestions.  As for limiting requests.  Another good point that the OP can look into if required.

Comment: Oh how I abhor `string.Empty`. `""` is *so* much shorter and not a jot less clear. But in general, this is a very clean implementation. +1

Comment: @Leonid "sometimes", such as? Do you mean `String.Empty`? (abhor++)

Answer (score 8):

You can also use recursion to avoid the goto in this case. Wrap the code in a method and let the method call itself instead of using goto.

**Warning:** Recursion can lead to a stack overflow. It's no problem here as long as the user doesn't click "Retry" too often, but when you remove the dialog the code becomes dangerous. Using an iterative solution (including the `goto` solution) doesn't have that drawback.

```
private void TableFill(myDataTable)
{
    try
    {
        oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + ex.Message, "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (res == DialogResult.Retry)
        {
            TableFill(myDataTable);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursion would be a different approach.  Fancy sharing the code?

Comment: I added some sample code.

Comment: Recursion is a dangerous option here.  If the problem is persistent you could end up with a stack overflow from repeated attempts.  It's not likely in the current form with a user prompt between each cycle; but you're creating a bomb that will be armed when a maintenance developer either replaces the prompt with an automatic retry, or uses this code as a template for an option that never has UI interaction, but doesn't otherwise change the implementation.

Comment: @DanNeely That's true, recursion should always be used with care. It's still a working solution in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I felt I had to downvote as this is a very dangerous answer that can result in a stack overflow.

Comment: I understand the downvote(s), but the code is still perfectly fine in a simple situation. I added a warning to my answer.

Comment: Good answer. One thing I would add is a number of retries parameter and deal with them tail-recursively.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `goto` as it is a clear sign of what is called spaghetti code.  @dreza has provided a much better solution.  You routines should be tightly cohesive, meaning they do one thing and they do it well.  Only wrap calls in `try`/`catch` if the call might throw an exception, then handle the exception and continue execution.

Comment: What about using goto inside switch, or to [`get out of deeply nested loops`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), is it also spaghetti code?

Comment: @ANeves +1 Using a goto once for a specific situation is "ok", but I personally try to find other solutions (exceptions, recursion, refactoring, etc.) first.

Comment: @ANeves - `goto case` is a perfectly legitimate use of `goto`.  Getting out of a deep loop should be refactored so that you can use a return statement instead, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use some form of asynchronous callback to call the method after its ended. It has been a year or so since I've programmed in C# and I've probably messed up the syntax, but you can use the Dispatcher to do this. You may need to use the Dispatcher appropriate to your UI framework (wpf, winforms, etc).

```
void myMethodName(myDataTable) 
{
    try { oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable); }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (res == DialogResult.Retry) 
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { myMethodName(myDataTable); }); // myMethodName will be called after the method ends.
     }
}
```

This uses the dispatcher to schedule a myMethodName() to be called again after your current instance of myMethodName() has exited and other queued methods have executed. This should avoid any problems of a stackoverflow.

Update:
Another way to do this, if you want to stay in the same method could be something like this. It is fairly concise and give the closest match to your current architecture. It does block which may or may not be desirable.

```
do 
{        
    DialogResult retry = null;
    try { oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(myDataTable); }
    catch (Exception ex) { retry = MessageBox.Show("Can't load data:\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }  

} while (retry == DialogResult.Retry);
```

Comment: This approach increases the level of complexity (volume of skull sweat required to reason about code that contains such a call) for such a simple problem.

Comment: Asynchronous callbacks are considered very simple to experienced programmers. Novices should learn this pattern. It should be a standard part of a programmers tool box to increase code readability and decrease bugs.

Comment: (*"and decrease bugs"* would benefit from an example.) I don't like this approach, because if other methods rely on this method's side-effects this approach will bite the programmer's hand. But it's a nice tool to know, yes.

Comment: I think the classic bug it reduces is preventing recursion overflow in an automated retry situation. Using asynchronous calls also frees up other items to render between retries and does not block the UI. I can imagine a situation where a coder does an automated retry every second in a while loop, the code always raises an exception and the user never gets back control of the UI. I agree it could cause problems if following code depended on success. Though, any code depending on the table fill should be placed in the try block.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of the `TrySomething` with out parameter pattern, so I would sooner do the following:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        possiblyFailingOperation();
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        reportError();
        if (abortRequested())
            throw;
    }
}
```

A `TrySomething` function makes sense when there's several places that call the same exception-throwing function and they all want to immediately catch and handle a single kind of exception said function may throw.  For example, `TryParse` often makes sense as parsing may be common and may have only one failure state (no parse).  It makes sense to do

```
if (!TryParse(x, out i))
    i = default_value;
```

When there's only one function that calls the `TrySomething` function, the added benefit is significantly less; we end up obscuring what exception is thrown and losing the ability to rethrow if necessary.

If this is all insignificant, a try function may be worthwhile; however, I'd use it in reaction to a common pattern, not in anticipation of one.

Comment: *"I'm not a fan of the TrySomething with out parameter pattern"*: **why not?** If `DoSomething` returns void, why should `TryDoSomething` need any out parameter? A concrete example: `TrySendEmail(to, message)`.

Comment: @ANeves: I've updated the answer to explain my reasoning.